# iPhone app crash with unknown error

Tags: iphone, ipad, crash, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing an application to take photos and upload the photos to remote server.

I have customized camera view using overlay view. App allows to take more than 1 photos per time and photos will be saved to device just after taking photos. When I am taking photos app gives memory warning and then crash. Followings are the from crash report. I have talked with Apple support team and they said this is not due to memory issue. This is because of trying to send an action to one of your controller object that no longer exists.

> OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J2)
>   Report Version:  104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS
>   (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x73980000
>   Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue:
>   com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed: 0   libobjc.A.dylib
>     0x34499c9a objc_msgSend + 18 1
>   UIKit
>     0x30a8bc1a
>   -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 86 2   CoreFoundation
>     0x308f056a -[NSObject(NSObject)
>   performSelector:withObject:withObject:]
>   + 18 3   UIKit                            0x309feec2 -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 78 4
>   UIKit
>     0x309fee62 -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:]
>   + 26 5   UIKit                            0x309fee34 -[UIControl
>   sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 32 6
>   UIKit
>     0x309feb86 -[UIControl(Internal)
>   _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 350 7   UIKit
>     0x309ff41c -[UIControl
>   touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 336 8
>   UIKit
>     0x309e452e
>   _UIGestureRecognizerSortAndSendDelayedTouches
>   + 2194 9   UIKit                          0x309e3bfa
>   _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateObserver + 690 10  CoreFoundation
>     0x30957a2e
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION**
>   + 10 11  CoreFoundation                   0x3095945e __CFRunLoopDoObservers +
>   406 12  CoreFoundation
>     0x3095a754 __CFRunLoopRun + 848 13 
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
>   14  CoreFoundation
>     0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52 15
>   GraphicsServices
>     0x30269418 GSEventRunModal + 108 16 
>   GraphicsServices
>     0x302694c4 GSEventRun + 56 17  UIKit 
>     0x30a10d62 -[UIApplication _run] +
>   398 18  UIKit
>     0x30a0e800 UIApplicationMain + 664 19
>   hand-e-pix
>     0x000025a4 main (main.m:14) 20 
>   hand-e-pix
>     0x0000254c start + 32

Can anyone please help me to identify what cause this problem?

Many Thanks

Regards
Chin

Comment: How did you set up the overlay view? Can you put some code here?

Comment: This is a good example given by apple.Hope this will help you.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could easily be related to a retain/release issue. Make sure you balance your reetain/release calls. Also make sure you do not reference any deallocated objects in your code.

You might want to take a look at enabling NSZombieEnabled in order to track this one down.
You can find information about how to enable it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html).

Comment: Thank you very much Claus, 
I was straggling to find a proper answer for a long time. I have found the problem with use of NSZombieEnabled. That is very use full variable. I have deallocated the autorelease variable. Thanks again.

Comment: @Chinthaka You're welcome. Just a little advice since I can see you're new on SO. Always remember to accept an answer if it solves your problem ;-)